# Customize jasper reports at the runtime of the program

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a reporting system using jasper reports in Java. In this system, I need to customize or align some text fields in the report during runtime. Is it possible to redesign the report during runtime? If it so, how can it be done.

It should be as deleting the field which is not relevant and to relocate the fields such as changing its co-ordinates by drag and drop.

How to do it or any other alternative solutions available. I don't want create From scratch like by using dynamic reports. I have details only in detail band.

[Data in Detail band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr5TI.png)

Comment: Jasper is a _template_, meaning the general structure of the report is fixed, but the content can be assigned at runtime.  Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes. for eg: Name : something. that something is retrived from the database and it was sent to printer. But In some case to I wanna fix that that Name has to align 0.5 inch left at run time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Is it possible to view the jrxml file in the design view. so that we can edit the jrxml, save it and compiled to jasper report. I need to change the template structure. Is there any other way.

Comment: Yes, I believe that IntelliJ and Eclipse have Jasper plugins that let you edit the jrxml template in the IDE.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I need to edit the jrxml at the run time for example from the installed application,I have to edit it without any editor, save it and compile it.

Comment: Describe your problem more fully.  It is not a typical use case to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have designed a report for my customers in jasper reports. That report prints as continuation to the preprinted sheet. In some case preprinted paper can vary and its unpredictable, the some alignment have to be made to the jasperreport template for the specific customer. how to solve this, the preprinted may vary depends on the customer, but the content remains same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, All I need to know is, whether it is possible to change the design in a frame at runtime. Which means the end user should be able to make changes in the position of fields, so that he could print the details in any format he wants.

Comment: I think the easier solution would be to workaround this and use a common template.

Comment: @AnoopRS `I need align some text fields` - You can use conditional styles, for example. `Is it possible to redesign the report at the runtime of program in java?` - Yes, you can use *JasperReports API* or *DynamicReports API* or *DynamicJasper API*

Comment: @AlexK, Thanks for your comment. can you elobrate your answer so that I could have better view over it.

Comment: @AlexK, Customer should able to redesign the existing jrxml file. (i,e) I should able to open the jrxml in the design view to the user.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have tried the common template, even it causes some problems in printing. because they are using preprinted sheets with some texts already printed and the printer has to print as a continuation to the sentences. They wish to design so that they could have their own style.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Once again have a look at the question. In my detail band of jrxml I have to change the element position by drag and drop, without the ireport designer.

Comment: @AlexK Could you share how to use dynamic jasper in this problem. I don't want to create a report from scratch. Already had a template, edit it at runtime and generate a jasper file.